# Token auth rules for fungible tokens

Tags: spl-token

There is [Metaplex Token Auth Rules](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-auth-rules) tool that allows setting permissions for programmable NFTs. Is there a similar tool for setting up additional validation rules, but for fungible tokens created by `spl-token`?